# Need to hack joystick so I can simulate its input from raspberry pi

Tags: potentiometer

I need to trigger a joystick from a raspberry pi. What I mean is, I want to be able to solder to a gamecube controller's board and trigger the input from a raspberry pi. I have little to no experience with electrical work. From what I understand, joysticks are just 2 potentiometers. Is there any way I can replicate the output of the joystick so I can simulate and trick the gamecube controller into registering joystick movements?

Comment: it may be easier to replace the whole controller with a custom device

Comment: Please provide a schematic of the "gamecube controller", whatever that is. We need to see how the potentiometers are used in that device.

Comment: To "trigger" means to cause something to happen suddenly as, for example, a gun trigger would. That's not what you want. You want to "emulate" a joystick using a Raspberry Pi (note capitals).

Answer (score 1):

There are two obvious ways to do it.

1. Use a 'digital' potentiometer to replace the resistances of the analog joystick pot. The [MCP4331](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP4331) is one example. It has 4 digital pots and an SPI interface. It comes in a TSSOP surface mount package, so you might want to use a TSSOP to DIP adapter for testing on a breadboard or wiring it by hand.
2. Use a DAC (digital to analog converter) to produce a voltage like the original pot did. The [MCP4802](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/MCP4802) has two 8 bit DACs and an SPI interface. It is available in DIP packaging, which may be a bit easier to work with.

Comment: I have tried to measure what the joystick does when moved and the voltage is varied. I have tried soldering to the data line and replicating the measured voltages into the gamecube controller board but that didnt work. Do I have the wrong idea?